How to show junk character in textbox from string c#
I'm trying to read the data from UDP client and show it in textbox
UDP packets are received from IP Camera (China Models)
Successfully I am able to read the packets and store it in List<string>
List<string> responses = new List<string>();

byte[] bytesRead = client.Receive(ref receiverEndPoint);  //Data packets are received here from the camera

responses.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesRead));

I'm displaying the response to textbox.
foreach (var str in responses)
{
    tbResult.Text += "\n\n" + str;
}

When I am trying to display the string to textbox, only few characters are displayed

In visual studio debugger, responses contains all the characters


Looks like when you set the Text property of the TextBox it will copy the string until the first '\0` (NULL) byte. Maybe there's a property to overcome this, not sure.

You could also split the bytes into segments using the 0 as a separator, because maybe they function as a message separator and you could read them into an array of messages.

It's basically this question, but I guess you may need to add an extra bit to show \u0002 and \u0005, not sure how VS debugger does it, but it seems to be something with Unicode.

Tip: if you want to see bytes, then the ideal view is like in hex-editor: show decimal/hex values and their ascii representation at the same time. You don't need convert byte array to string, rather convert each byte to hex-string and ascii-character.

WinForms has ByteViewer control.

It looks like the endpoint is trying to send you a JSON, but you're reading the raw packet data, then try to convert the raw data with, for some reason, Encoding.ASCII (more probably should be UTF-8, but the communication protocol should be explained in the documentation of your device). As a result, you see only the part of (mangled) text before it's truncate by the first \0

You may try something like this.
string rawData = "?+\0\u0001\0\0\0";
    // Convert the raw data to a visible format
    string visibleString = ConvertToVisibleString(rawData);

    // Display in the TextBox
    textBox.Text = visibleString;

or
textblock.Text = visibleString;
private string ConvertToVisibleString(string input)
{
// Replace non-printable characters with a visible representation
return string.Concat(input.Select(c =>
(c >= 32 && c <= 126) ? c.ToString() : $"\x{(int)c:X2}"));
}
